# Why aren't my columns width adjustment working?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
 .tscroll {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<html>
        <div class="tscroll">
                <table   cellspacing="100" align="center" style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                </tr>
                  <td style="border:0.5px solid #E1DEE6; width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color:white;">
                    <div>
                    <h2> Column 1 </h2>
                    <div>
                    <p>
                        Coming soon  
                    </p>
                     </div>
                  </td>

                  <td style="border:0.5px solid #E1DEE6; width: 400px; height: 500px; background-color:white;">
                    <div>
                    <h2> Column 2 </h2>
                    <div>
                    <p>
                        Coming soon  
                    </p>
                     </div>
                  </td>
                 
                 <td style="border:0.5px solid #E1DEE6; width: 400px; height: 500px; background-color:white;">
                    <div>
                    <h2> Column 3 </h2>
                    <div>
                    <p>
                        Coming soon  
                    </p>
                     </div>
                  </td>
              <td style="border:0.5px solid #E1DEE6; width: 400px; height: 500px; background-color:white;">
                    <div>
                    <h2> Column 4 </h2>
                    <div>
                    <p>
                        Coming soon  
                    </p>
                     </div>
                  </td>

                  <td style="border:0.5px solid #E1DEE6; width: 400px; height: 500px; background-color:white;">
                    <div>
                    <h2> Column 5 </h2>
                    <div>
                    <p>
                        Coming soon  
                    </p>
                     </div>
                  </td>
                  <td style="border:0.5px solid #E1DEE6; width: 400px; height: 500px; background-color:white;">
                    <div>
                    <h2> Column 6 </h2>
                    <div>
                    <p>
                        Coming soon  
                    </p>
                     </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, the columns are super slim. I want them to be bigger, but when I change the width in `<td>` it doesn't do anything.
I'm trying to create a scrollable ( on columns) table and need the columns to be large enough to only be showing 2 columns at the time, then scroll right to see the rest.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: try use `!important` or `min-width`, probably got override somewhere along the way. If not, try use padding in td tag.

Comment: How about adding horizontal margin to the div inside <td>?

Comment: @YotamDahan min-width works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use min-width to declare importance

```
 .tscroll {
  min-width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need spacing in the td elements and not the tr elements. You can do it by these two methods:

```
td{
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

or

```
td{
  padding: 400px;
}
```